# io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.httpclient- Error HTTP 403 executing

Tags: webdrivermanager-java

While I am replacing traditional way to initiate browser instance with WebDriverManager library, getting this error- io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.httpclient- Error HTTP 403 executing

**imported dependency**-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That error should not happen in version 5.3.0. If that version is correct and you experience the 403 error, please open an issue here: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues

Comment: Thanks for your reply @BoniGarcía                                                                                                  
Yes. I try with version 5.3.0 but issue still exist. So I opened an issue https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/891